# CreateWindowEx() function don't create window and throws error

Tags: c++11, winapi

I try to create a window, but I encounter an error, but the compiler don't show an error;

`GetLastError()` returns 1407, but sometimes 0.

If error 0 or 1407 doesn't matter, the window still can't be created.

There is my code:

WINDOW.H

```cpp
class Window {

protected:

    MSG msg = { 0 };

    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { 0 };

    HWND hMainWindow = { 0 };

    WCHAR WindowClass[MAX_NAME_STRING];
    WCHAR WindowTitle[MAX_NAME_STRING];

    INT ScreenWidth = 0;
    INT ScreenHeight = 0;

    RECT MainWindowDimensions = { 0 };

public:

    static void onError(int error);
// WNDCLAS INIT
    int InitMainWindowClass(WCHAR WindowClass[MAX_NAME_STRING], DWORD R, DWORD G, DWORD B); 
// Creat Window
    int CreateMainWindow(WCHAR WindowTitle[MAX_NAME_STRING], INT X, INT Y, INT Width, INT Height);
    int BroadcastMessages();

};
```

WINDOW.CPP

```cpp
int Window::InitMainWindowClass(WCHAR WindowClassInput[MAX_NAME_STRING], DWORD R, DWORD G, DWORD B) {

    wcscpy_s(WindowClass, WindowClassInput);

    ScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    ScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(R, G, B));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hInstance = HInstance();
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)MainWindowProcedure;
    wcex.lpszClassName = (LPWSTR)WindowClass;
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    //error code 1407

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) {
        Functions func;
        int i = GetLastError();
        std::string si;
        std::string text = "ERROR " + (si = func._itos(i)) + " - Windows Class is not Registered!";
        std::wstring wtext = std::wstring(text.begin(), text.end());
        MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, (LPWSTR)wtext.c_str(), L"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int Window::CreateMainWindow(WCHAR WindowTitleInput[MAX_NAME_STRING], INT X, INT Y, INT Width, INT Height) {

    MainWindowDimensions = { X, Y, Width, Height };
    
    wcscpy_s(WindowTitle, WindowTitleInput);

    hMainWindow = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        wcex.lpszClassName,
        WindowTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW| WS_VISIBLE,
        ScreenWidth / 2 - MainWindowDimensions.right / 2,
        ScreenHeight / 2 - MainWindowDimensions.bottom / 2,
        MainWindowDimensions.right,
        MainWindowDimensions.bottom,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        HInstance(),
        NULL);

    if (!hMainWindow) {
        Functions func;
        int i = GetLastError();
        std::string si;
        std::string text = "ERROR " + (si = func._itos(i)) + " - Window is not Created!";
        std::wstring wtext = std::wstring(text.begin(), text.end());
        MessageBox(hMainWindow, (LPWSTR)wtext.c_str(), L"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(hMainWindow, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hMainWindow);

    return 0;
}

int Window::BroadcastMessages() {
    
    while (1) {

        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {

            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
                return 0;
            }

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            //TODO: Do Something Else

            Sleep(0);
        }
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowProcedure(HWND hMainWindow, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch (msg) {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            return 0;
        }
        {
            Events.onClose(hMainWindow, wParam, lParam);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        default:
        {
            DefWindowProc(hMainWindow, msg, wParam, lParam);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should be `wcex.cbSize = sizeof wcex;`, since the type may or may not be `WNDCLASSEXW`.  And the cast at `wcex.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)MainWindowProcedure;` can never help and only ever hides problems, so remove it.  Also remove the cast at `wcex.lpszClassName = (LPWSTR)WindowClass;` which is pointless at best and may hide severe errors.

Comment: @BenVoigt "*And the cast at ... can never help and only ever hides problems, so remove it*" - same with all of the other casts being used, too.

Comment: I Remove Cast, but this dosen't help.

Comment: It helps. It may not solve your immediate issue, but it helps *us* concentrate on what's wrong, without getting distracted. A [mcve] would obviously be ideal.

Comment: _itos() this is my defined function. This function converts integer to std::string.

Comment: There's [`std::to_wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) for that, and has been for more than a decade now.

Comment: You didn't show the function `MainWindowProcedure` which is kind of important. My guess is that you didn't forward all unhandled messages to `DefWindowProc` (or failed to propagate the return value).

Comment: As I predicted: `DefWindowProc(hMainWindow, msg, wParam, lParam); return 0;` always returns 0. It should return what `DefWindowProc` returns. `return DefWindowProc(hMainWindow, msg, wParam, lParam);` This means in particular that you return `0` to `WM_NCCREATE` which means "Do not create the window." Your next problem is that you ignore `WM_PAINT` messages so you will be stuck in an infinite paint loop.

Comment: I don't think the shown `MainWindowProcedure` would even compile as shown, as it has some syntax mistakes in it.

Comment: I fix syntax mistakes in MainWidowsProcedure and program worked.